# Using Codashop or Hoyoverse top up page with VPN to get Genesis Crystals with US prices

Tags: genshin-impact

Good evening. I am from North America but my country has an increased 16% on the top up prices, the 100usd package is 116usd via PSN, and it's even worse in mobile, charging 125usd. Recently I read about people evading their countries prices using Codashop or topping up using a VPN on the Hoyoverse site. Is the Genshin account safe using these methods?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against trying to use a VPN to get different region prices. I suspect that this could be seen as an attempt to scam Mihoyo and ground for a suspension or even a ban.

That said, I did some research on the other option you mention since I saw that name posted a lot. Seem it is completely legit and safe, that site should have an official partnership with Mihoyo.

Some references:
[Hoyolab post](https://www.hoyolab.com/article/173911/)

I looked into what the site actually asks you.

[image]

only a UID. And since normal users don't have any way to buy credit for a specific uid, the only way I see this working is thru a direct collaboration with Mihoyo.

There are two issues you may want to consider though.

**First Issue: you are on PSN, it is unknown if Codashop supports that**
You mention PSN, so I assume you are a Playstation user. Well, let me tell you something then. The increased price you have on PSN (should be 5.49 VS 4.99) is not Mihoyo fault. That is Sony's extra greedy "tax for letting you on my platform" thing.  So on that front the price you see on Codashop makes complete sense.Problem is that since the game is also multiplatform with cross-play enabled Sony also devised another ultra-nice way to try to make people unable to escape their platform tax.

[image]

See the fine notice here, courtesy of Sony. It is possible that Codashop gems are PC gems and thus unable to be used while playing on a Playstation console. It is unclear how their site works with multiple platforms since the UID should stay the same: if you play on PC and PS on what "platform" the gems will end up on? I strongly advise that you contact Codashop customer service at the very best, and you could also consider asking Mihoyo too for extra confirmation.

**Second Issue: Security and trust**
This may be paranoia. Codashop seems to be a quite well known platform that probably exist because it is very convenient for games operators to escape the taxes they have to pay to the various platforms they operate on. You see, when I talked about "Sony's special tax" I didn't want to imply that Mihoyo doesn't have to give part of their IOS/Android sales to those platforms too, it is just that Sony quotes are higher. So, it is very convenient for Mihoyo to give an option that is both available to people that are unable to buy extra items thru their platform on PC and that probably nets them more money than the IOS/Android/PSN stores do.
That said, you are still putting another intermediary in the system, and with each new chain ring there is a new potential attack surface. Nowadays it should be almost impossible to attack your account just with an UID but... ask you if you want to.
Also, this is one more shop you have to create an account on and give your payment details to. Do you trust them?

Technically, if you just wanted to escape Sony tax you could also use cross-play and a PC account to buy crystals directly from Mihoyo. But that means you have to be able to play on pc in the first place, and also having two attack points to protect: your psn account and your Mihoyo one (one of the advantages of playing ONLY on PSN is that your Mihoyo account does not have any access credential that can be compromised, because it is only access via OAUTH).

If I was in your place I would try to keep up with the prices for now. In the meantime, join the ones who spam the #sony twitter account with request to have the same prices as other stores.